# How to work out why Apache is attempting "execmem"?

Tags: apache-httpd, selinux

I'm getting audit messages from SELinux saying that it denied Apache doing execmem:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(05/06/16 19:51:43.058:181060) : avc:  denied  { execmem } for  pid=123456 comm=httpd scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=process
```

The PID is one of the Apache PIDs and it keeps cycling between the processes.

From what I've read, execmem for Apache is generally [not normal](https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-selinux-list/2007-August/msg00173.html) and a [Bad Idea™](https://www.axivo.com/resources/selinux-booleans-explained.22/), and that makes sense.

I've tried tracking an origin by tallying timestamps with Apache logs, but if affects various requests across various sites (PHP-based with and without MySQL, Python/mod_wsgi-based, plus internal Apache "OPTION" requests) and I can't find anything consistent.

Rather than try to explain my setup to get people to debug it, **what I want to know is how do I work out where the execmem call is coming from so that I can work out whether it is important?**

(Note: I know there is an SELinux boolean to set to allow it, but I don't want to do that without first understanding why it is trying it. There is no point in having SELinux if you're going to turn it into a sieve, much like there's no point having a firewall and then opening every port that ever complains without checking whether it is important or not).

Comment: I've done a bit of investigating and it doesn't seem to be Python/mod_wsgi. I commented out all mod_wsgi lines, reloaded Apache, the WSGI processes were stopped but the errors continued.

Comment: I've finally found the problem through testing on a VM (means I control all requests) and running smaller and smaller test cases. Eventually turned out it was PHP7's PCRE JITing (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php). Doesn't answer the wider and more general case of "how do I work out where Apache is trying to do execmem from when SELinux complains about it", though!

Comment: There's a Fedora 25 bug report: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1398474, a [RHEL report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1398474), and there's an upstream [pcre report](https://bugs.exim.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1749). Thanks to the folks who had this figured out ahead of time, it helped me a lot when I did an F25 upgrade and saw these denials happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently came across this problem with SELinux on Amazon Linux with PHP7. I used a combination of [Russell Coker's excellent `LD_PRELOAD` trick](https://etbe.coker.com.au/2010/07/12/write-execute-mmap-ld-preload/) (to intercept `mmap()` calls and trigger an assertion failure) and gdb (to view the call stack as soon as the assertion failure is triggered) to check which function wants to *execmem*.

I also came to the conclusion that PHP7 PCRE JIT was the culprit. Putting `pcre.jit=0` in `php.ini` fixed it for me.

### Detailed steps

1. log into your machine as root
2. download the `mmap.c` source code from [here](https://etbe.coker.com.au/2010/07/12/write-execute-mmap-ld-preload/) into /root/mmap.c
3. build the code with `gcc -shared -g -fPIC mmap.c -o mmap.so`
4. now run Apache through gdb, intercepting mmap() calls: `LD_PRELOAD=/root/mmap.so gdb /usr/sbin/httpd`
5. you're thrown into gdb. Because Apache forks child processes, it is important to tell gdb to jump into them by typing `set follow-fork-mode child` after the `(gdb)` prompt
6. now kick off Apache by typing `run` after the `(gdb)` prompt
7. wait patiently until some HTTP request triggers the code that in turn triggers the assertion in `mmap()`, you're then back in gdb.

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff7fe9840 (LWP 28370)]

0x00007ffff638d5f7 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56

56        return INLINE_SYSCALL (tgkill, 3, pid, selftid, sig);
</pre>
8. Type `bt` (backtrace) to see the call stack:
<pre>(gdb) bt

#0  0x00007ffff638d5f7 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56

#1  0x00007ffff638ece8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90

#2  0x00007ffff6386566 in __assert_fail_base (fmt=0x7ffff64d6ca8 "%s%s%s:%u: %s%sAssertion `%s' failed.\n%n", assertion=assertion@entry=0x7ffff7bda990 "!(prot & 0x4) || !(prot & 0x2)",

    file=file@entry=0x7ffff7bda985 "mmap.c", line=line@entry=27, function=function@entry=0x7ffff7bda9af <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.2774> "mmap") at assert.c:92

#3  0x00007ffff6386612 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x7ffff7bda990 "!(prot & 0x4) || !(prot & 0x2)", file=0x7ffff7bda985 "mmap.c", line=27, function=0x7ffff7bda9af <__PRETTY_FUNCTION__.2774> "mmap")

    at assert.c:101

#4  0x00007ffff7bda93e in mmap (addr=0x0, length=65536, prot=7, flags=34, fd=-1, offset=0) at mmap.c:27

#5  0x00007ffff79a6b86 in alloc_chunk (size=65536) at sljit/sljitExecAllocator.c:101

#6  sljit_malloc_exec (size=4440) at sljit/sljitExecAllocator.c:204

#7  sljit_generate_code (compiler=compiler@entry=0x555555b14ad0) at sljit/sljitNativeX86_common.c:296

#8  0x00007ffff79bf74e in _pcre_jit_compile (re=re@entry=0x555555b14650, extra=extra@entry=0x555555b14750) at pcre_jit_compile.c:6434

#9  0x00007ffff79c1fc3 in pcre_study (external_re=external_re@entry=0x555555b14650, options=1, errorptr=errorptr@entry=0x7fffffffa3c8) at pcre_study.c:1354

#10 0x00007fffed2edcbc in pcre_get_compiled_regex_cache (regex=0x7fffd8a04000) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.9/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:487

#11 0x00007fffed2ef21f in php_do_pcre_match (execute_data=0x7fffec419ab0, return_value=0x7fffec419870, global=1) at /usr/src/debug/php-7.0.9/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c:655

<...>
```

9. the culprit is easily identified. Stack entry 11 gives you a hint to check PCRE and entry 5 is the actual call that goes awry.

Comment: Just trying this out. It looks promising, but I can't get it working yet. Step 7 never seems to happen and all I get logged are "AH00052: child pid xxxx aborted (6)" (segfaults, apparently) and "mmap: Assertion… failed". No change to gdb when it happens, though. Static content servers cleanly, but pages that should debug just get "secure connection failed". I must have done something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Did you set gdb to follow into forked childs with the `set follow-fork-mode child` before you entered `run`? The fact that the mmap() call triggers an assertion failure tells us that the LD_PRELOAD trick worked.

Comment: Definitely ran that command inside gdb. Repeated several times and no success. However, suggestion in https://httpd.apache.org/dev/debugging.html to use "run -X" instead of the "follow-fork-mode" seemed to work for me. Stack trace was: #0: raise() … #4: custom mmap(), #5: sljit_generate_code(), #6: _pcre_jit_compile() … #9: php_do_pcre_match(). Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the -X tip :-)

Comment: Could it be a runner or other config issue that means "follow-fork-mode child" didn't seem to work as expected for me? I'm using prefork with Webtatic's PHP 7.0.